# Trouble with Return Values

Tags: ruby

I am taking a lesson on codecademy in which I am currently stuck do not know how to proceed - it is regarding return values.

The instructions are:

Write a method that takes an integer as an argument, and returns that integer times ten. Call times_ten in your code after you define it and print out its return value.

What is given in the script is:

```
def times_ten(integer)
  # your code here
end

# call times_ten here
```

This is the example it gives but I am having a hard time understanding:

```
def first_squares(number_of_squares)
  squares = []

  idx = 0
  while idx < number_of_squares
    squares.push(idx * idx)
    idx = idx + 1
  end

  return squares
end

puts("How many square numbers do you want?")
number_of_squares = gets.to_i
squares = first_squares(number_of_squares)

idx = 0
while idx < squares.length
  puts(squares[idx])
  idx = idx + 1
end
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you having problems understanding what a return statement is or does?

Comment: ...So you want a tutorial to help with your tutorial. Interesting. I've never seen that before.

Comment: It appears, your example script is not related to your problem. What your example script does is print 'n' numbers of square numbers. That's the reason why you are having a hard time understanding it.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
def ten_times(n)
  n*10 # you don't have to use 'return' explicitly
end
```

ten_times(n) -- but put in an actual integer instead of n (or maybe you have to puts or print it, depending on what they want)

Your example is not really related to your outcome.

Comment: I basically just put the code below and it seems to do exactly what the instructions are asking of me... although it is still saying it is incomplete.

`def times_ten(integer)`
 `return integer * 10`
`end`

`times_ten(20) `

Comment: So it is still saying it is incomplete? Maybe you are supposed to 'puts' or 'print' the times_ten(20) to have the outcome be actually printed.

Alternatively, maybe the test wants you to gets.chomp the integer first and then pass it into the function, based on the example you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

The example script should be like this:

```
def ten_times(integer)
  # integer * 10 #for implicit return 
  return integer * 10 #for explicit return
end

print ten_times(any number you want goes in here)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following code at www.rubyplus.biz:

Implicit return:

```
def times_ten(integer)
  integer * 10
end

p times_ten(1)
```

Explicit return:

```
def times_ten(integer)
  return integer * 10
end

p times_ten(2)
```